# Trouble with Image Rendering in Flutter - Seeking Guidance

Tags: flutter

Good afternoon to everyone.

I am a very new developer on flutter, and I made a simple app, to show an image

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
        title: Text("I am Rich"),
      ) ,
      body: Center(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('Images/diamond.png'),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ));
}
```

I followed the flutter documentation, to resolve this issue

https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images

I specify in my yaml file

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
   - Images/
```

in the console I get

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "Images/diamond.png".

and my folder is named Images

Comment: Is the `Images` folder under the project folder? Or is there an `assets` folder before it? In that case `assets/` has to be part of the string too: `assets/Images/diamond.png`

Comment: The Images folder is in the root of the project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use all lowercase letters for assets folder path.